# get last value of the other partition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I got this SCD table:

| start_date | end_date | partition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 15:35:09.856 | 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 | 1 |
| 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 | 2022-05-18 13:26:31.195 | 2 |
| 2022-05-18 13:26:31.195 | 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2 |
| 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 | 2 |
| 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 | 2022-09-01 11:10:20.777 | 1 |
| 2022-09-01 11:10:20.777 | 2022-09-01 11:21:26.526 | 1 |

I would like to know for each partition the last value of start_date and end_date of the other partition (there are only two). for the given table:

| start_date | end_date | partition | max_start_date | max_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-08 15:35:09.856 | 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 | 1 | null | null |
| 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 | 2022-05-18 13:26:31.195 | 2 | 2022-03-08 15:35:09.856 | 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 |
| 2022-05-18 13:26:31.195 | 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2 | 2022-03-08 15:35:09.856 | 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 |
| 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 | 2 | 2022-03-08 15:35:09.856 | 2022-03-09 14:57:36.610 |
| 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 | 2022-09-01 11:10:20.777 | 1 | 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 |
| 2022-09-01 11:10:20.777 | 2022-09-01 11:21:26.526 | 1 | 2022-08-02 10:12:02.441 | 2022-09-01 11:10:01.019 |

I tried some last_value window function and didn't made it. like this:
, last_value (start_date) OVER (partition by partition = '1' order by start_date asc) as last_start_date_partition
, last_value (end_date) OVER (partition by partition = '1' order by end_date asc) as last_end_date_partition
is there any option to inject a condition to window function and make it function that way?

Answer (score 0):

Using `dense_rank`:

```
with cte as (
   select (select sum((s1.start_date < s.start_date and s1.partition != s.partition)::int) 
     from scd s1) r, s.* 
   from scd s
),
n_part as (
   select dense_rank() over (order by c.r) dr, c.* from cte c
)
select np.start_date, np.end_date, np.partition, max(np1.start_date), max(np1.end_date) 
from n_part np left join n_part np1 on np1.dr = np.dr - 1
group by np.start_date, np.end_date, np.partition
order by np.start_date, np.end_date
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/S0D7PeM-).

Answer (score 0):

Using windows functions and gaps-and-islandish approach:

```sql
SELECT start_date,
       end_date,
       PARTITION,
       max(start_date) OVER (ORDER BY grp RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING EXCLUDE GROUP) max_start_date, -- use max value without current group
       max(end_date) OVER (ORDER BY grp RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING EXCLUDE GROUP) max_end_date -- use max value without current group
FROM
  (SELECT start_date,
          end_date,
          PARTITION,
          sum(lag) OVER (ORDER BY end_date) AS grp -- use cumulative sum to create a group
   FROM
     (SELECT *,
             CASE
                 WHEN lag(PARTITION) OVER (ORDER BY end_date) != PARTITION THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END lag -- use lag to determine if the partition has changed
      FROM mytable) t) tt
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3NxkPbSypf18FKrEQkmhvP/0)

Answer (score 0):

You could do a self-left join and aggregate as the following:

```
select T.start_date, T.end_date, T.partition_,
       max(D.start_date) max_start_date,
       max(D.end_date) max_end_date
from SCD T left join SCD D
on T.start_date > D.start_date and 
   T.partition_ <> D.partition_
group by T.start_date, T.end_date, T.partition_
order by T.start_date
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/l5YECUir)